# Erro: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, json, android-studio

Eu estou tentando consumir dados de uma API usando retrofit, porém sempre que eu tento me conectar retorna esse erro. Eu estou usando uma classe que é um Array desses objetos (SisalfaCatalog) e jogando o retorno dentro dela, porém não dá certo. Segue o código:

A interface do serviço:

```
public interface SisalfaService {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://app.sisalfa.dcx.ufpb.br/v1/api/";

@GET("contexts")
Call<SisalfaCatalog> listPalavras();
```

}

A classe com o Array dos objetos:

```
public class SisalfaCatalog {
public ArrayList<Palavra> palavras;
```

}

Conteudo da API:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sala",
    "image": "https://app.sisalfa.dcx.ufpb.br/v1/static/images/dababcd96ab5f7854f820ff926c9acaa.jpg",
    "sound": "",
    "video": "",
    "createdAt": "2018-06-22T19:31:18.745Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-06-22T19:31:18.745Z",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "neto",
        "email": "jose.silvaneto@dce.ufpb.br",
        "firstName": "José",
        "lastName": "Antonio da Silva Neto",
        "photo": null
    }
},
```

E o main com a chamada do serviço:

```
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(SisalfaService.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    SisalfaService service = retrofit.create(SisalfaService.class);
    Call<SisalfaCatalog> call = service.listPalavras();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<SisalfaCatalog>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SisalfaCatalog> call, Response<SisalfaCatalog> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Errr, a conexão não deu certo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bem, deu certo aparentemente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SisalfaCatalog catalog =   response.body();

                for(Palavra p : catalog.palavras) {
                    Log.i("Nome: ", p.getName());
                    Log.i("Id: ", ""+p.getId());
                    Log.i("Url: ", p.getImage());

                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SisalfaCatalog> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Errr, não deu certo. "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("Erro: ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: O JSON que está vindo começa com `[`, portanto é um array. O código esperava que fosse um objeto. Dentro do array há um objeto (começando com `{`), acredito que ele esperava que fosse esse objeto. Quando for array tem que tratar como array e quando for objeto tratar como objeto. Não conheço a API que está usando senão dava mais detalhes.

Comment: como eu faco pra tratar como array? na interface eu coloco um Array dentro da call?

Comment: Como falei, não conheço a API que você está usando.

Comment: Tudo bem. Eu fiz essa modificação na interface e funcionou.

Comment: Bom trabalho. O inverso também é possível, trazer somente um objeto no JSON, mas pelo visto o que você queria era o ArrayList.